# Does anyone know where can find the original 'SDeanComponents' for Delphi. I have tried searching Google, but without any results. Many Thanks

Tags: delphi, components

I am coding a newer version of a secure drive cleaner and I remember that Sarah had a comprehensive, and well written, file system component. Her site is no longer working but I guess somebody has a copy of them somewhere. I had the full SDean set but sadly, my NAS has just taken a nosedive so I cannot retrieve the code.

I have searched extensively, without any luck. I am hoping someone might know where I can get the full set again.

Comment: https://github.com/t-d-k/LibreCrypt/tree/master/SDeanComponents

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=SDeanComponents and https://duckduckgo.com/?q=SDeanComponents do list that repository for me. "_Her site is no longer working_" - then search for an archive like https://web.archive.org/web/20120506110803/http://www.sdean12.org/